# Cortana won't pronounce my name correctly

Tags: cortana, speech

Cortana keeps spelling out my name, even though I'm teaching her how to pronounce it.

When I go to [Cortana's settings](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/cortana/cortanas-settings) and click <kbd>change my name</kbd>, she asks me what she should call me. I enter my name, which is *Bas*. She proposes to call me *B-A-S* (she says my name spelled out). It's actually pronounced like *bahs*, so I click the <kbd>that's wrong</kbd> button.

Now she asks me to tap the microphone and say my name the way I'd like her to pronounce it. At the next screen I click the play button and she's got the pronunciation right, so I click <kbd>next</kbd> and go back to the main page of Cortana.

At this point, I ask Cortana: "*What is my name?*" and she just says it spelled out like she did before I went through the whole process of changing the pronunciation.

Why won't she do this right? Is there any way to make her? Is my name too short for her to differentiate between the choice of saying it and spelling it?

Answer (score 1):

Tap and hold vowel ('a' for the instance) and choose the appropriate sound for your name. [Bæs may be]

Comment: Doesn't work, she keeps spelling my name!

Comment: Can you tell me your language and region? Because I'm getting different sounds.

Comment: My language is "_English (United States)_" and my region is "_United States, English (United States)_", speech setting is also "_English (United States)_".

Comment: Seriously I don't know why Cortana showing partiality to you. I tested with your name as bas, Bas, BAS etc. with different 'a' sounds, it never made a 'B-A-S' unless I gave those letters separately ("B A S").

Comment: Well, I'll just file a report with Microsoft then :) It's just 'Bas' though, nothing special about the letters I type it with. I've been talking to her for over a year now, maybe she just doesn't like me anymore.